# Problem with installing react 18 + typescript + redu-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a problem with creating project with new react 18/ typescript  and redux-toolkit.
I am trying to install @reduxjs/toolkit, but I see an error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @reduxjs/toolkit@1.8.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @testing-library/react@12.1.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^12.1.4" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.0.0" from react-dom@18.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!     peer react-dom@"*" from @testing-library/react@12.1.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!       @testing-library/react@"^12.1.4" from the root project
npm ERR!     react-dom@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   2 more (react-scripts, the root project)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional react@"^16.9.0 || ^17.0.0 || 18.0.0-beta" from @reduxjs/toolkit@1.8.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit
npm ERR!   @reduxjs/toolkit@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peerOptional react@"^16.9.0 || ^17.0.0 || 18.0.0-beta" from @reduxjs/toolkit@1.8.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit
npm ERR!     @reduxjs/toolkit@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed by a new release in the next few days - until then you will have to run the command with `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps` as shown in the command.

Edit: should be working now: https://twitter.com/acemarke/status/1509540340088328196